# Nokogiri loop only returning the first thirty or so results

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I've written some code that loops through this [results table](http://rio-de-janeiro.vivanuncios.com/computador)
and prints the href of every entry.  The loop works fine until it hits the tr 26.  Does anyone have any idea why?  This is what my code looks like right now:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

#Setup

listings_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://servico-informatica.vivanuncios.com/computador+rio-de-janeiro-capital/'))
listings_page.css( "#classified_table tr.classified").each do |listing|
  puts listing.css(".summary .classified-link")[0]["href"]
end
```

I checked the CSS and it doesn't seem like anything changes markup wise among the TRs.  I'm aware there are different types of TRs (classified vs advertisement) but that's fine since I don't want to extract the ads.

Comment: what is your issue..not getting..

Comment: because there are only 35 `tr`'s ...

Comment: sorry, what I mean is that it only shows the first 26TRs, it's not returning the others which are of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

The document at that URL has only a single `table` element with an `id` of `classified_table`.

That table has just one `tr` element (with no `class` attribute) of two columns. The first element is another table with 39 `tr` elements. 35 of them have a `class` that includes `classified`, while the other four have a class of `vs-advertisement`.

You are getting the correct result.

Comment: Hi Borodin, I understood that there are two different classes inside that table (classified vs advertisement) but the problems is that the parser is only going down to TR26, when in fact there are 35 TRs.

Comment: If I add `puts listings_page.css( "#classified_table tr.classified").size` to your code I get 35.

Comment: Sorry to pester you!  .size does work in outputting the number 35, but I don't understand how to move from that to actually outputting the all the hrefs.  Loops don't seem to work

Comment: @JonathanKorn: The code you show in your question correctly displays the 35 values for the `href` attribute.